# LISP: Join multiple lists but not flatten

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, flatten

I have

```
(setq a '(0 1))
(setq b '(3 4))
(setq c '(6 8))
```

and I wish to get the output `x` as:

```
((0 1)(3 4)(6 8))
```

Please advice.

Comment: It is generally advisable to think in bindings, not in assignments.  Say `(let ((a '(0 1)) (b '(3 4)) (c '(6 8))) #|something that returns the joint lists|#)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow missed something really basic here!

```
(setq x (list a b c))
```

Comment: Alternatively: `\`(,a ,b ,c)` or `(cons a (cons b (cons c '())))` :-)